# Error in MongoDB and mongoos

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crud, mean-stack

I am trying to modify the value of an array object in NodeJS using Mongoose. I have written the following code with the help from internet snippets. However the code doesn't seem to be working. I am getting this error: How can I solve it?

```
error in updating { name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'cannot use the part (appointmentList of appointmentList.patientID) to traverse the element ({appointmentList: [ { patientID: "99999999", dateAndTime: "XXXXX" } ]})',
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 16837,
  errmsg: 'cannot use the part (appointmentList of appointmentList.patientID) to traverse the element ({appointmentList: [ { patientID: "99999999", dateAndTime: "XXXXX" } ]})' }
```

This is the code:

```
function addOrUpdateAppointment(jsonObject, isDatabaseOperationSuccessful) {
    var docID = jsonObject.doctorID; // this is _id from db sent to the doctor upon logging in
    console.log("jsonPssed: ", {_id : docID});
    DoctorModel.findOne({_id : docID, 'appointmentList.patientID': jsonObject.appointment.patientID},function(err, foundData) {
        console.log("found data", foundData);
        if(err) {
            console.error("error in find doctor for adding the appointment", err);
            isDatabaseOperationSuccessful(false, foundData);
            return;
        }
        else {
            // since no document matched your query, add the appointment
            if (!foundData) {
                DoctorModel.update(
                    {_id: docID},
                    {$push: {appointmentList: jsonObject.appointment}},
                    function(err) {
                        if(err) {
                            console.error("error in adding", err);
                            isDatabaseOperationSuccessful(false, foundData);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("adding successful");
                            isDatabaseOperationSuccessful(true, foundData);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
            // since that appointment already exists, update it
            else {
                foundData.update(
                    {_id: docID, 'appointmentList.patientID' : jsonObject.appointment.patientID},
                    {$set: {'appointmentList.$.appointment': jsonObject.appointment}},
                    function(err, updatedData) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error("error in updating", err);
                            isDatabaseOperationSuccessful(false, foundData);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("updating successful", updatedData);
                            isDatabaseOperationSuccessful(true, foundData);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the Schema:

```
doctor: {
   _id : ObjectID(571fb65678fcd63c29db423a),
   xyz: "sdfs",
   appointmentList : [
    {patientID:"123", date: "25 MARCH"},
    {patientID:"456", date: "26 MARCH"}
   ]
}
```

This is the JSON that I am passing to the update method:

```
{
    "doctorID": "571fb65678fcd63c29db423a",
    "appointment": {
      "patientID":"123",
        "dateAndTime": "TTTTTTTTTTTT"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do something like below:

```
    DoctorModel.findOne({_id : docID } , {'appointmentList.$.patientID': jsonObject.appointment.patientID},function(err, foundData) {
       console.log("found data", foundData);
    });
```

This will first search all the document where doctor id is `docID` and then appointment for that patient ID.

Comment: I am getting this error:
`{ name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Positional projection \'appointmentList.$.patientID\' does not match the query document.',
  waitedMS: 0,
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'Positional projection \'appointmentList.$.patientID\' does not match the query document.',
  code: 2 }`

Comment: Ok so I have fixed this problem with this query: `{_id : docID, 'appointmentList.patientID': jsonObject.appointment.patientID}, {'appointmentList.$.patientID': jsonObject.appointment.patientID},` However the update is still not working. Gives this error:

`cannot use the part (appointmentList in appointmentList.patientID) to traverse the element`

Comment: so you are able to get the data?

Comment: Yes. The required object is found but I can't update the data.